# app crash when I use capture="camera" into input element on android device

Tags: android, html, cordova, web, android-camera

I would like to enable only the camera option by using:

```
<input type="file" name="photoInputElem" capture="camera" accept="image/*" style="display:none;" (change)="handleUploadedPhoto($event.target.files, photoInputElem)">
```

but when I trigger these input, the app crashes.

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: 7:35.218 31365 31365 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.****.**** , PID:  ****
12-20 13:27:35.218 31365 31365 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity  I guess.

Comment: Did you implement onActivityResult in your code?

Comment: it's hybrid app.

Comment: Did you declare CAMERA permission?

Comment: these are the permissions that I have.
 <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
        </config-file>

Comment: @MorSmadja - Doing a short search online reveals that the error is connected to the onAcvtivityResult method. I would check inside your code what is parallel to that method and debug it.